# excel vba: selecting recently created shapes

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet where people have to sign using a pen and tablet. On excel we are using "start inking" for this process. I would like to select, resize, and move the signature after it is done. I used macro recording and figured out how to resize and move, but apparently I can only select all shapes or select a shape I know its name (ink 17) which I don't know. I gave it a little thought and realized that maybe i get get around it by selecting the latest created shape. Also, a signature may contain one or more curves which means that I have to remember the previous ones and select the rest (when a second or third person signs). I am sure that there is a way to do it but I have spend that last few hours without any luck.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and the errors you got or why it it didn't do what you wanted

Comment: What triggers the macro?

Comment: @dbmitch right now I am trying the following     "ActiveSheet.Shapes.SelectAll
    MsgBox ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name" and I am getting "the item with the specified name wasn't found

Comment: @JohnColeman I am writing the code into "Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)" for now. but if there is a way to trigger the code right after a new shape is created that would be amazing (and might fix the problem)

Comment: What does this mean ... "I know its name (Ink 17)  which I don't know"

Comment: I used macro recorder in an attempt to get a hint. this is what i got: "Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Ink 21")).Select
End Sub"

Comment: If you are simply adding (as opposed to sometimes deleting) shapes, it should be easy enough to store `ActiveSheets.Shapes.Count` in a public variable whenever the macro runs, and then compare the new count with the old count to see how many shapes have been added between runs. The newer shapes will be the ones with the larger indices.

Comment: @JohnColeman that is somewhat what I have started doing. To overcome the deleting problem, i am using ActiveSheet.Shapes(i).Name to store the shapes names (and exclude based on names). However this is a very tedious method for what is seemingly an easy task. Isn't there a cleaner way?

Comment: I don't think that there is an easier way for what you are trying to do. Perhaps you can move the signing to a userform and transfer the signature when the form closes.

Comment: _"Also, a signature may contain one or more curves which means that I have to remember the previous ones and select the rest (when a second or third person signs). "_: Would you explain this with an example? What does _"remember"_ actually mean?

Comment: @user3598756 the signature is represented by several curved shapes. Some signatures have a dot for example, with the curve, that's 2 objects. as for your next question, I have to obtain several signatures. so if i have 10 shapes, these could be 1 signature or 10 signatures. I need to save (or remember grammatically) which is which (basically i need a reference)

Comment: what are the signal that tells you a signature is beginning and, eventually ending? you may post a screen shot of some samples

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be, to have them sign where no other shapes are. Let's assume they have the range `M11:Q31`. This sub would half the height and width of all shapes which upper left cell is in that range (having a "background" which starts at `N11` would not be affected).

```
Sub kjhdrle()
  Dim x As Variant, y As String
  y = ""
  For Each x In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If Not Intersect(x.TopLeftCell, [M11:Q31]) Is Nothing Then
      If y = "" Then
        y = x.Name
      Else
        y = y & vbLf & x.Name
      End If
    End If
  Next
  If y = "" Then Exit Sub
  ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Split(y, vbLf)).Select
  If InStr(y, vbLf) Then Selection.ShapeRange.Group.Select
  Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 0.5, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
  Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 0.5, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
End Sub
```

I kept is as simple as possible. It will also group the items if more than one so when resizing, the anchors will also scale. (Without, each element would shrink at its own anchor).

A different way, would be an automatic renaming of shapes you do not want to be processed... having something like "not_me_" in front of the name. Then when running the code, simply ignore shapes wich start with that string. And after processing, the shapes which where used by the sub, are renamed to `"not_me_" & [shape].name`, so they will be ignored next time ;)

If you still have any questions, just ask.

Comment: I like your second way. Quite clever.

Answer (score 0):

I just came along this question since I had a similar request. What now worked for me was: You can get the latest shape by comparing the amount of shapes on the sheet before and after creation.

```
Sub Get_latest_Shape()

Dim lngCount As Long

    'Save the sheets current amount of shapes before adding a new one.
    lngCount = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count

    'Add a shape.
    >> your shape-adding code here <<
    
    'Address the latest shape by calling the old shape count +1.
    MsgBox (ActiveSheet.Shapes(lngCount + 1).Name)
    
End Sub
```